# display tags jsp tags

Tags: java, jsp, struts

i am using diaply tags library for displaying my tables.But i cant use the <% %>
tagst there.If i try to us it it gives me error.but i can use  tag there.
If i try to use followin code in my jsp it give an error sayin  shoul hav a matcheing ending tag.
i have follown java code in jsp

```
List<Course> = (List<Course>)request.getAattribute("crc");
```

here Course is a class/bean.

can anyone suggest me such library that i can use with struts for auto paging,displaying list in tables,and with other features provided by display tag.I want to use struts and i want the view to look good and yet easy to devlop.that is i want to achieve high class userinterface with littel effortr toward displaying o/p / view.

can anyone provide the example of disploay tag with struts

Comment: You need to post the full code.  Clearly getAattribute wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the name attribute of the table tag (normally like this:)

```
<display:table name="crc" ...>
</display:table>
```

To use the crc List as the basis of Javabeans to display.

See http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/displaytag/tagreference.html#display-el:table for more information about the table tag.

Comment: i am passing the list of object from the previous page to this page.
So i want to retrive it in this jsp by using request.getAttrivutr("crclist");  but if i typecats it to List<Course> i get error saying <course> has no matching ending tag.

Comment: Try just placing "crclist" as the name of the object without any casting or scriptlets - if it is in the request, it should be able to be picked up with the "name" value - if that doesn't work, try requestScope.crclist - it all depends on what scope that list is in.